# "sched: RT throttling activated" KVM host - what does this mean?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kvm-virtualization, kernel

Ubuntu 12.04 64bit - under a KVM parent.
32 cores.
So we seem to be having some load issues.
We have noticed this line in kern.log: "kernel: sched: RT throttling activated"
What does this mean?
Is the KVM parent throttling the host?
This is on a single parent - single child KVM parent/host.

Comment: Are you running KVM on a realtime kernel?..

Comment: I can't tell - this is a hosted VPS.

Comment: What? You have a VPS with _32_ virtual CPU's?

Comment: yes it's a dedicated VPS - one child one parent - lookup 'baremetal' - lots of advantages include on the fly resizing, image backups, etc.

Comment: Sounds like a Media Temple "Nitro" or a LiquidWeb "Storm Server"

Comment: @voretaq7: I have exactly the same issue under a KVM host. Any news here?